# reading a text file that contains a variable name and passing it with updated value in VB

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I'm having trouble trying to pass text while reading from a text file into a string variable where the text contains a variable that needs to be replaced with a value.  The text is a SQL query that need a value replaced from another string variable.

```
    Dim i As Integer

    i = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index
    TestPlanID = DataGridView1.Item(0, i).FormattedValue.ToString
    status = DataGridView1.Item(3, i).Value.ToString

    AvgRespTimeAll_S1Query = IO.File.ReadAllText(SQLFilePath & "\AvgRespTimeAll_S1Query.txt")
```

My variable 'TestPlanID' is not being replaced when called.  Anyone have any suggestions please?

Comment: And why it should be replaced? The text retrieved is just a string assigned to AvgRespTimeAll_S1Query. The compiler cannot assume anything with that text. You should add the code that extracts the value to assign to your variable

Answer (score 3):

I don't see any code that's actually trying to replace anything, but you can use the .Replace function
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx

```
Dim newString = AvgRespTimeAll_S1Query.Replace("oldText", "newText")
```

Comment: Thanks.  The Replace did the trick.  Can't believe it was that simple.  Appreciate your help

Comment: No problem, please mark it as the answer if it solved your problem!